# Job de SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito por favor si me pueden dar ideas de como solucionar lo siguiente:

Tengo una base de datos a la cual le llamaré `Principal` que está en `SQL Server`, ésta importa información de otras bases de datos (`Oracle` y `SQL Server`) para mostrarla en un sistema que solo manipula y muestra la información de diferentes formas (reportes, gráficos, etc).

La importación de estos datos se realiza por medio de un `Job` que se ejecuta cada **2 horas** (es estrictamente necesario esa calendarización ya que la información cambia constantemente).

El `Job` tarda alrededor de **10 minutos** en terminar de ejecutarse e importar la nueva información, el problema es que en ese lapso de tiempo los usuarios no pueden consultar datos porque el Job lo tengo de la siguiente forma (*ejemplo*):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Principal
INSERT INTO Principal
SELECT * FROM TablaDeOtraBaseDatos
```

Además, si sucede algún error con el `Job` ya no tengo datos.

¿Alguna idea de como solucionar esto? Ó si es que estoy haciendo mal el `Job`?

Gracias.

Comment: cada vez que corre el job debe borrar todos los datos y volverlos a cargar de 0??

Comment: No necesariamente, el asunto es que lo hice así porque algunos datos a veces el valor de unas columnas cambia, por ejemplo: hace 2 horas la columna Estado tenía el valor Borrador, 2 horas después tiene el valor Enviado. Entonces la forma que se me hizo más fácil para eso fue, borrar todo y volverlo a cargar

Comment: puede sar más fácil, pero definitivamente más ineficiente. Cuántos datos aproximadamente se cargan cada vez?

Comment: Más de 125 mil registros aproximadamente

Comment: Casi nada, no debería estar tomando 10 minutos, la verdad

Comment: El asunto es que trae información de diferentes bases de datos, que no tienen índices, a su vez algunas columnas se les tiene que hacer un trato especial, etc etc. Alguna una idea de que solución implementar?

Comment: Pues de partida, deberías cargar la información de estas otras bases en tablas en una base de datos intermedia (típicamente llamadas "staging"), donde cargues la información, y hagas estos "tratos especiales" (y todas las transformaciones necesarias). Una vez listo esto, deberías realizar un bloqueo exclusivo (sólo temporalmente) de las tablas de destino y cargar los datos (ojalá sólo los datos necesarios)

Comment: Y ese bloqueo exclusivo se realiza por medio de SQL Server, existe algo para eso? O debe ser a nivel de la página web?

Comment: Lo del bloqueo exclusivo se hace mediante script en SQL, pero es lo menos relevante de mi comentario

Comment: No lo veo tan relevante pues me es de mucha utilidad saber cómo se hace eso bloqueo

Comment: Puedes usar el hint `TABLOCK` al momento de hacer el `INSERT`. Sí debes entender que nadie más podrá modificar datos en la tabla durante ese tiempo. Lo más importante es que puedas hacer el procesamiento y precarga de datos en una base de datos paralela, y sólo insertar cuando eso ya esté listo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo he implementado algo parecido de la siguiente forma:

1. Creo una tabla `PrincipalTemporal`, tiene que ser un tabla física real copia idéntica de `Principal`
2. Realizo la importación de los datos en `PrincipalTemporal`
3. Verifico el correcto funcionamiento de este proceso
4. Si la información se incorporo correctamente: a) `DROP TABLE Principal` y luego `sp_rename 'PrincipalTemporal', 'Principal'`

De esta forma en caso de error no destruímos la tabla, por supuesto tendremos información desactualizada, pero según el escenario esto puede tener menor importancia a no tener nada.

Comment: Por favor no hagas esto a menos que se cumplan una serie de condiciones. Por ejemplo que no hayan índices relevantes, llaves primarias, foráneas, etc

Comment: El usuario ya está haciendo un TRUNCATE así que imagino que por ese lado no habría problemas

Comment: Truncate mantiene los índices creados, así como llaves primarias y foráneas a menos que ésta sea la tabla principal. También hay que preocuparse de triggers y otras cosas

Comment: Suena interesante ésta opción pero tiene razón @Lamak, en mi caso la tabla Principal sólo tiene índices... pero si hago una copia de la tabla Principal por script, los índices se deberían de crear también, no es cierto?

Comment: Si de acuerdo  @Lamak..

Comment: La tabla secundaria se tiene que crear con los mismos índices de la original, desde el Enterprise se puede "scriptear" la creación de la tabla  y debería trasladar al script también los índices.

Comment: Qué pasa si un usuario hace una consulta a la tabla justo en el momento que se hace el sp_rename?

Comment: A ver... el DROP y sp_rename lo metería en una transacción, no debería demorar mucho, aún si lo hiciera, entiendo que la transacción estaría bloqueando la tabla completa por lo que se supone que las consultas a la misma debiera esperar a la finalización del bloqueo.

Answer (score 0):

no tunques la tabla antes de que se vacie la información, tienes varias opciones!, las que se me vienen ahorita a la mente son:

**Opción 1:** Ejecuto el trabajo y lleno tablas diferentes con similares nombres, que luego que termine el trabajo, puedo pasar esa información a las tablas reales! Es decir, a).- Corro el trabajo que dura 10 minutos, al final del proceso, trunca y copias cada una de las tablas, eso sera cuestion de segundos.

**Opción 2:** Puedes utilizar una columna en cada tabla que te sirva de referencia para determinar qué registro es viejo y que registro es nuevo, es decir, configuro una de las columnas de tipo *INT* y en *DEFAULT* en INSERT que se le asigne el numero 0 en cada una de las tablas que toma los informes, configuro que el o los reportes tome solo los registros que tengan el valor 1 en la columna ***nueva***, asi pues, en el *JOB* coloco que rellene todas las tablas, acto seguido borro todos los registros que contengan al valor 1, y luego, actualizo todos los registros existentes con valor 0 a 1 y será violento.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaria que en lugar de hacer ese proceso tengas una table temporal en la bd ejemplo: Certificate_Temp la principal seria Certificate y hacer el siguiente proceso:

1. Truncar la tabla temporal
2. Cargar la informacion en la tabla temporal
3. Ejecutar un SP que haga la mezcla entre la dos tablas usando la funcion merge de SQL [Merge statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)

**Merge** mezcla dos tablas en una, le puedes indicar que campos quieres que actualice si el valor existe o si se tienen que borrar o insertar, dependiendo de las variables que escojas, ademas al final te muestra que acción tomo en cada row update,delete o insert.
Este se encargara de hacer el trabajo duro por ti, un ejemplo sería:

```
MERGE dbo.Certificate AS T
    USING Certificate_Temp AS S
    ON (T.SerialNumber = S.Id) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
        THEN INSERT(SerialNumber,EffectiveDate,ExpirationDate,Expired,Revoked,Subject,UserId,Type) 
        VALUES(S.Id, S.EffectiveDate,S.ExpirationDate,S.Expired,S.Revoked,S.Subject,@UserId,'S')
    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE SET T.ExpirationDate = S.ExpirationDate,T.EffectiveDate = S.EffectiveDate, T.Expired = S.Expired,T.Revoked = S.Revoked
    --WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
        --THEN DELETE 
    OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

De esta forma tu tabla jamas estará inaccesible